# ggforest output not visible in r-notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, rnotebook

I am trying to show a `ggforest` plot, the plot gets rendered perfectly in r-studio but it does not show up in *r-notebook*.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

data("veteran")
cox = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ karno+celltype, data = veteran)
ggforest(cox, data = veteran)
```

When I run the above code, it creates a plot in R-studio (r-script), but does not create any plot in *r-notebook*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

**Edit:**
I looked at the definition of `ggforest` and the last statement of that function is `invisible(p)` where `p` is a `ggplot` object. Could that be somehow related to graph not showing up in the notebook. I also tried to write the same function without `invisible(p)` but ran into errors as it could not find certain functions like `.get_data()` and `tidy()`.

Comment: Does it work if you assign the plot a name and then `print()` it?

Comment: @aosmith, thanks, it works, but it plots the same graph twice. How do I get rid of second graph. I tried `p = ggforest(cox, data = veteran); p` , `p = ggforest(cox, data = veteran); print(p)`, `p = ggforest(cox, data = veteran); plot(p)`. All of these plot the graph twice.

Comment: Well, I got a workaround, thanks to your idea. I assigned the plot name in one chunk and called that in next code chunk. Now it plots only once.

Comment: Glad you found a work-around but definitely seems odd.  I was also seeing double plots when I would run the whole chunk but not when I ran the code directly.

Comment: @aosmith, were you able to reproduce the actual issue. I opened a issue on github but concerned person is not able to reproduce the issue. It will be beneficial for everyone you could tell if you face the same issue on your machine.

Comment: Yes, if I put your code into a chunk in a Notebook and run the chunk then the plot does not appear in the Rmd file or output.  If I then add `print()` I get two plots when I run the chunk.  I'm on Windows 7 with R 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.1.453.